# Add custom header from within a prototype

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, request-headers

I have prototyped the `XMLHttpRequest` to add additional functionalities.
But when I try to add a custom header to the call it does not work (no errors and no calls in the chrome developer toolbar)

My code:

```
(function(){
var originalOpenFunction = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, pass) {

    //Add custom header
    this.setRequestHeader('custom-header', 'value');

    originalOpenFunction.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
};
})();

$.ajax("http://www.jsfiddle.net");
```

When I remove the `setRequestHeader` line, I get the error I expected (cross-origin not allowed).

**Note** Although I use jquery to test the javascript, the solution to this should be in native javascript.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfAZN/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose errors by:

```
$.ajax("http://www.jsfiddle.net").fail(function (e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

You will get:

> InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': the object's state must be OPENED.

This means you need to call `open()` before you call `setRequestHeader()`.

Then you will run into the cross domain issue. Make sure you're not trying to do a cross domain request to an unsupported domain. The shell runs from `http://fiddle.jshell.net`.

Requesting that domain *works* (returns HTML).

See: http://jsfiddle.net/HfAZN/3/